# Tomcat8 constantly displays the https-jsse-nio-443-exec log

Tags: jsse, tomcat8.5

I have a problem with the data mapping in logs of Tomcat. There are the same information in the logs and it’s unusable. Could you please check and advise me how set and get correct data in the logs?

```
  28-Nov-2018 23:19:11.535 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-35] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
     java.lang.NullPointerException

   28-Nov-2018 23:19:26.548 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-38] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
     java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please find the logs below.

```
Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your log entry in regards to

"Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!"

Appears to be a red herring. It is only a warning and it appears the method was removed because it is "obsolete" (since Java 1.6)

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6254234